# Excel rows and columns consolidation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet as below

[image]

and I am looking for consolidation as below

[image]

Can you please help

Comment: What exactly have you tried to solve this?

Comment: I tried vlooup and INdex combination as per google...no luck.

Comment: What is the range of conditions you can encounter?  Is it always one entry per row, with 1 and only one entry per column per card?  If not, how do you combine multiple values?

Comment: Its only one entry per row. The values of V1, V2 and V3 will change...but its always only one entry, similar to the image above

Comment: Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use a pivot table:

[image]

Drag Card to the Rows window, and V1, V2, and V3 to the Values window.  Use the filters to deselect blanks.

Comment: It doesnt help. If I do that, its giving me actual values. To simplify your understanding, I gave 1, 2s and 3s. The actual value would be date and time...for V1, V2, V3

Comment: my Actual sheet looks exactly like this...

Comment: @Mani, we can know only what you tell us, we have no way of knowing how your actual worksheet is different from what you describe, and you still haven't described what the desired result should look like. However, if the values are date/times, those are stored as numbers, and formatted to be readable in the form you want. This solution should work to show the date/times in the result. You just need to format the results in the pivot table as date/times.

Comment: Thanks you all for your response and apologies for not being clear with the question. I have edited and posted the actual images of my original sheet and desired result. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what question, but suggest this as a possibility. I setup a schedule that counts the number of times something is populated in a column with a value for a certain card.  Please the screen cap.  I changed your example to show it with dates[image]

Comment: Thanks you all for your response and apologies for not being clear with the question. I have edited and posted the actual images of my original sheet and desired result. Hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

Since your screenshot is useless for copying data to a test sheet, I have used what I think is a valid simplified version, where there is only a single entry per row, but multiple entries per column.

To get from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

You can use `Power Query` present in Excel 2010+ (as a free add-in from Microsoft).  aka `Get&Transform` in Excel 2016+.

- Select column `Card`
- `Unpivot other columns`
- Select Column `Attribute` (will be created when you do the Unpivot)
- `Pivot` with Values Column = `Value` and Advanced Options = `Don't Aggregate`

[image]